# Is it possible to set pre-existing anaconda2 as an py2 environment in anaconda3?

Tags: python, anaconda

Previously I have anaconda2 installed under `~/anaconda2`. Recently I installed anaconda3 to `~/anaconda3` and replaced:

```
export PATH="/home/xxx/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

with:

```
export PATH="/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Every time when I want to use python2 I would manually edit the `.bashrc` and change that line back to `export PATH="/home/xxx/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` and start a new terminal session.

Recently, I noted [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/switch-environment) that it is possible to switch python3 to python2 without creating a new session. However, When I run `conda create --name py2 python=2.7`, I get the following output:

```
conda create --name py2 python=2.7
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py2

  added / updated specs: 
    - python=2.7


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.15              |       h1571d57_0        12.1 MB
    ... (many lines not important)
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.3 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0           
    .... (many lines not important)    

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

It seems that this will initiate a new python2 installation. My question is: **Is it possible to instruct `conda create` to use the existing `~/anaconda2` as `py2` environment rather than install a new python2 environment de novo?**

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @darthbith, creating a new installation  and getting all the non-standard packages I had insalled before take much time. I thought conda might be smart enough to known that some packages are already there and no re-installation need.

Comment: You can create an `environment.yml` file from your old anaconda install and use it to create a new environment in anaconda3. The command is `conda env export`

Comment: @darthbith. This still won't use the existing one. It seems that users are not allowed to do this by design. Anyway, I find I can use the `--clone` to create an exact copy of previous environment.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why you would want to use exactly the same files though. Why not just recreate the environment and delete the `anaconda2` install?

Comment: @darthbith, Just want to find where there is a quick way :). In addition, I found [another way](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments) to clone the previous installation.

Comment: Awesome, I would say that link to the conda docs is your best answer :-)